# alertDialog from async object

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Code I've tried so far:

```
Object SomeGeneralApi(){
    private lateinit var mAlertDialog: AlertDialog.Builder
    fun setContext(currentContext: Context) {
        mAlertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(currentContext)
    }

    fun someAsyncFun() {
        mAlertDialog.setTitle("Example")
            .setMessage("Example message")
            .setPositiveButton("accept")
            { _, _ ->
                //some action
            }
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel") { _, _ ->
                //some action
            }.show()
    }

    fun someAsyncFun2() {
        mAlertDialog.setTitle("Example2")
            .setMessage("Example message2")
            .setNeutralButton("OK", null)
            .show()
    }
}
```

`someAsyncFun2` is representing with 3 buttons, unfortunately (I'd to get with only OK button),
and I can't call the dialog anymore afterwards.

Also I'm using Jetpack Compose and would like it to show the dialog from everywhere in my single activity program with its dark mode as well.

Comment: Why are you using `AlertDialog.Builder` in jetpack compose?

Comment: You're using the same dialog builder - it saves the fields set during first `someAsyncFun`, that's why you see 3 buttons when call `someAsyncFun2` on the next time. You can create a new builder each for each new alert or set positive/negative button titles to `null`. But I wasn't being able to reproduce "I can't call the dialog anymore afterwards" - in my [sample](https://gist.github.com/PhilipDukhov/e0d939470d1aae0c6c96847b687ab96b) it works fine multiple times. Please provide a  [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)